# Load external website using ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

I want to load an external site from different domain [like: http://iqecommerce.com] in the iframe when I click the button by using jquery-ajax. I also want to show 'imafsdges' div as an ajax loader in the iframe before loading is complete.

My following code is like below

```
<input type="button" id="check1" value="Click to load"  /><br/>
<div id="imafsdges" style="display:none;"> Loading</div>
<iframe  id="theiframe" class="frameToChange" name="some" width="70%"    height="400px">     </iframe>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/YSd9g/

Comment: Yes I'm using jquery and the solution is need to be using jquery-ajax

Comment: I'm expecting the answer soon